# Connecting to worklight on iOS crashes when coming from background without network

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst

I am using iOS7 iPhone simulator

1. Download the native iOS sample app: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/iOSNativeApp.zip
2. Download the worklight server: http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v600/NativeAPIForIOS.zip
3. Run the project and configure it to connect/invoke worklight server, everything should be fine

NOW:

a. Press Home

b. disconnect any internet connectivity
   (a and b can be either way around)

c. enter the app & then go to background again (Home button)

d. it crashes (see image below)

So you have to enter the app from background without connectivity and then press Home. Go to background and foreground number of times if it doesn't happen for you first time around. The crash seems to be related to pausing of heart beat in WLClient.

[image: Worklight heart beat crash]

Comment: This defect is logged and is being looked at. Thanks.

Comment: Wanted to clarify, Idan is aware that this is a separate issue from the original iOS7 heartbeat issue you were having. There is a separate defect logged for this that is being looked into.

Answer (score 0):

This is a defect that has been logged and will be fixed in a future release.